# Detecting self-postback in a dynamically created UserControl

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a button and a panel. When the user clicks the button it loads a usercontrol and adds it to `panel.Controls`. I need to bind a grid in the usercontrol when the usercontrol first loads (`Page_Load`) but not when the user clicks a button inside the usercontrol, aka triggers a postback in the usercontrol. I can't use `Page.IsPostback` because it returns true when the user clicks the main button which loads the usercontrol. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give the buttons inside of the user control a CommandName and check the value of the CommandName.  You can also check the type on object sender to determine the control that caused the post back.

Don't forget that you will have to re-add the user control on each post back after it is dynamically created (in an event that occurs before Page Load), so you will need to implement a mechanism to determine that the user control was added in the panel.

Answer (score 1):

It's primitive, but you can check for any control that caused the postback by comparing the value coming from:

```
Request.Form.Get("__EVENTTARGET")
```

This returns the uniqueID of the targeted control; check this to determine which button caused the postback, and act accordingly.